# Hibernate one-to-many joins on multiple tables

Tags: java, database, hibernate, calendar, criteria

So, I have a class called app.  app has a one-to-many relation with a class called user.  user has a one-to-many relation with a class called login. Login contains fields that represent the time the user logged out, expressed as timestamps. If I wanted to make a hibernate criteria query that returns the users that have signed on within the past x numbers of days, how would you do it?  This is what I have so far, and it just returns all users regardless of when they logged on:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new  java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar2.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days*(-1));
java.util.Date past = calendar2.getTime();
java.sql.Timestamp pastTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(past.getTime());    
Criteria LoginCriteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class, "App")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("App.appID", appid))
                    .createAlias("App.users", "user")
                        .createAlias("user.logins", "lg")
                        .add(Restrictions.ge("lg.endTime", pastTimestamp ))
                        .add(Restrictions.le("lg.endTime", currentTimestamp));
```

I am using timestamps to measure time.  I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria LoginCriteria = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("user.appId", "https://"+appid+".com"))
                .createAlias("user.logins", "lg")
                .add(Restrictions.ge("lg.startTime", pastTimestamp ))
                .add(Restrictions.le("lg.startTime", currentTimestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively I think this should work, though I don't have your structure set up to test it out:

```
Criteria LoginCriteria = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user")
      .add(Restrictions.eq("user.appId", "https://"+appid+".com"))
      .createCriteria("logins")
           .add(Restrictions.ge("startTime", pastTimestamp))
           .add(Restrictions.le("startTime", currentTimestamp));
```